# Finding value of unknown in factorial equation

Tags: permutations, combinations, factorial

What's the value of $n$ in the following equation?

$$2(2n-4)!= (n-4)!(n+2)!$$

I've tried coming up with an equivalent combination and expanding $(n+2)!$ but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Find a solution (or a couple solutions) for very small $n$, and then use induction to show that from that point onward, the left side grows faster than the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = 6$
$$2(2n-4)! = (n-4)!(n+2)!$$
$$\implies 2(8!) = 2!(8!)$$
Since the left hand side increases faster than the right, this is the only solution.